# Получения доступа к содержимому фрейма

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Есть `site1.ru`, на нём есть `iframe`, в котором подгружается `site2.ru`.
Также на `site1.ru` можно разместить скрипт, размещённый при этом на `site2.ru`

```
<script src='http://site2.ru/script.js'>
```

Поможет ли физическое расположение скрипта на том же домене, что и айфрейм обойти политику безопасности и получить доступ к DOM этого айфрейма? 
Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не поможет, неважно на каком домене расположен JS-файл, когда вы его подключаете его контекстом выполнения будет страница подключения, и обратиться к содержимому фрейма вы все равно не сможете.

Если у вас есть возможность встроить скрипт в подключаемый фрейм, то в этом случае можно организовать общение между окнами через Web Messaging API.

Во фрейме:

```
parent.postMessage({data: 'data'}, 'http://test1.ru');
```

В родительском окне:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    e.data; // {data: 'data'}
});
```